# Pandas - Find first occurance of number closest to an input value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

```
   time  speed
0     1   0.20
1     2   0.40
2     3   2.00
3     4   3.00
4     5   0.40
5     6   0.43
6     7   6.00
```

I would like to **find the first occurance of a number** ( in 'Speed' Column) that is **closest to an input value I enter.**

*For example :*

**input value = 0.43**

*Expected Output :*

**Speed : 0.40** &  corresponding Time : 2

The speed column **should not be sorted** for this problem.

I tried the below,but not getting the expected output.

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: According to your logic, I think there is nothing wrong with your output since `0.43` is the the closest to `0.43` !

Comment: Yes,but it should consider 0.40 as the closest, as its the first occuring value.

Comment: Then you need to define a threshold, otherwise, why wouldn't 0.2 be the closest?

Answer (score 2):

##### absolute closest

You can compute the absolute difference to your reference and get the `idxmin`:

```
speed_input = 0.43
df.loc[abs(df['speed']-speed_input).idxmin()]
```

output:

```
time     6.00
speed    0.43
Name: 5, dtype: float64
```

##### first closest with threshold:

```
i = 0.43
thresh = 0.03
df.loc[abs(df['speed']-i).le(thresh).idxmax()]
```

output:

```
time     2.0
speed    0.4
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: his Expected Output :

`Speed : 0.40 & corresponding Time : 2`

Comment: exactly! he should define a threshold first, thank you for the update

Comment: [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) ?

Comment: @jezrael `Series.abs` is not faster than `abs(series)` and it's shorter to type so I like this way ;)

Comment: Can't define a static threshold value ,unfortunately. It might differ for different datasets.

Comment: @JayashreeSridhar well you need to define a method somehow, or else how can you say that 0.4 is close but not 0.35 or 0.2? Even if you're using rounding, this acts as a threshold

Answer (score 0):

One idea is round both values:

```
df[[(df['speed'].round(1)-round(speed_input, 1)).abs().idxmin()]]
```